# Python Selenium Automation XPATHS is not functioning for Chrome DevTools Print section

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, chrome-web-driver

I am working on automation to download PDF from websites. In AWS website when I click on download that time print section open in my current tab which is chrome developer tool. I copy XPATH from this source code but it does not work in my automation script. Is there any way so I can access print section..

//*[@id="sidebar"]//print-preview-button-strip//div/cr-button[1]

I am trying to access this chrome by default print script which is inside  tag.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.